# sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier with CountVectorizer and additional predictor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have built a text classification model with sklearn's `DecisionTreeClassifier` and would like to add another predictor. My data is in a pandas dataframe with columns labeled `'Impression'` (text), `'Volume'` (floats), and `'Cancer'` (label). I've been using only Impression to predict Cancer but would like to use Impression and Volume to predict Cancer instead.

My code previously that ran without issue:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data['Impression'], data['Cancer'], test_size=0.2)

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = vectorizer.transform(X_test)

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight='balanced', max_depth=6, min_samples_leaf=3, max_leaf_nodes=20)
dt.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = dt.predict(X_test)
```

I've tried a few different ways to add the Volume predictor (changes in bold):

1) Only `fit_transform` the Impressions

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data[['Impression', 'Volume']], data['Cancer'], test_size=0.2)

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X_train['Impression'] = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train['Impression'])
X_test = vectorizer.transform(X_test)

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight='balanced', max_depth=6, min_samples_leaf=3, max_leaf_nodes=20)
dt.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = dt.predict(X_test)
```

This throws the error

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'csr_matrix'
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

2) Call `fit_transform` on both Impressions and Volumes. Same code as above except for `fit_transform` line:

```
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
```

This of course throws the error:

```
ValueError: Number of labels=1800 does not match number of samples=2
...
X_train.shape
(2, 2)
y_train.shape
(1800,)
```

I'm pretty sure method #1 is the right way to go but I haven't been able to find any tutorials or solutions for how I can add the float predictor to this text classification model.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ColumnTransformer()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer.html) will exactly solve this problem. Instead of you manually appending the output of `CountVectorizer` with other columns, we can set the `remainder` param as `passthrough` in `ColumnTransformer`.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import set_config

set_config(print_changed_only='True', display='diagram')

data = pd.DataFrame({'Impression': ['this is the first text',
                                    'second one goes like this',
                                    'third one is very short',
                                    'This is the final statement'],
                     'Volume': [123, 1, 2, 123],
                     'Cancer': [1, 0, 0, 1]})

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    data[['Impression', 'Volume']], data['Cancer'], test_size=0.5)

ct = make_column_transformer(
    (CountVectorizer(), 'Impression'), remainder='passthrough')

pipeline = make_pipeline(ct, DecisionTreeClassifier())
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
pipeline.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Use 0.23.0 version, to see the visuals of pipeline objects (`display` param in `set_config`)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hstack` to combine two features together.

```
from scipy.sparse import hstack
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
X_train_new = hstack(X_train, np.array(data['Volume']))
```

Now your new train contain both features. And if I may advice, use tfidfvectorizer instead of countvectorizer since tfidf considers the importance of words in each document/Impresion while countvectorizer only counts number of occurrences of words and hence a word like "THE" will have higher importance than those which really matter to us.